# Как с помощью языка си на unix очистить данные по номеру файлового дескриптора

Tags: c, http, websocket, unix

Извиняюсь за формулировку вопроса. Проблема такая. На сервер, написанный на си приходят данные. Он может обрабатывать их по протоколу http и ws. Если клиент сразу открывает ws соединение, то данные читаются нормально. Если же до этого приходили данные по http и номер дескриптора, который был создан для поддержания ws соединения, совпадает с номером дескриптора, который был до этого создан для открытия http соединения(при том что, при закрытие http соединения дескриптор закрывается с помощью close), то данные будут читаться с мусором с прошлых http запросов. Как почистить данные в дескрипторе, чтоб мусор при открытии нового соединения не читался?

Comment: Скорее всего это ошибка кэширования данных на уровне логики сервера, а не ОС.

Comment: @avp, сервер самописный, кэширования данных нет

Comment: Тогда проверьте, что http дескриптор сокета, который вы закрыли по close был единственным (т.е. нет его копий, полученных в результате dup() или переданных в другие процессы и не закрытых там. Возможно, после получения его из accept этому дескриптору надо сразу приписать FD_CLOEXEC)

Comment: @avp, да, он точно единственный

Comment: ОС какая? Никогда не сталкивался, но я бы попробовал в таком случае установить SO_RCVBUF в 512  байт (setsockopt()) перед close и прочесть их. Вообще, хотелось бы небольшой воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: На всякий случай,  [вот описание TCP connection termination](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination.htm), может найдете что-нибудь полезное для себя

Comment: @avp есть вызов на сброс хвоста без чтения.. Не помню как его.. Но тут похоже сокет на стеке и поэтому выдает тот же дескриптор на каждое сообщение.

Comment: А операции read вам подконтрольны, или может они внутри какой то библиотеки происходят ?

Comment: @Mike, да, подконтрольны